# Protected access in java not working

Tags: java, inheritance, public, protected

Consider class test

```
package access;

public class test {
    public String s;
    protected test(String s){
        this.s = s;
        System.out.println("access.test constructor");
    }

    protected void test1(String s){
        this.s = s;
        System.out.println("access.test test1 method");
    }
}
```

Consider class Operations

```
package data;
public class Operations extends access.test{

    Operations(String s){
        super(s);
    }

    public static void main(String args []) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Operations O = new Operations("Operations!");
        access.test t = new access.test("hello");//1
        t.test1("hi!");                          //2
    }
}
```

Constructor test and method test1 is not visible at lines 1 and 2. Why??

Comment: Working exactly as intended; you declared them `protected` and are attempting to access them from a class in a different package.

Comment: It's technically correct but error is there

Comment: Please read my comment. You **should** get an error, your code is **not** "technically correct"

Comment: I understand what protected access is.....What seems to be the problem @Brian??

Comment: Protected access is allowed for subclasses outside the package. Constructors can have any access modifier. Could you please be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 3):

In your `data.Operations.main()` you are attempting to instantiate `access.test` via `new`:

```
access.test t = new access.test("hello");//1
```

You can't do that. That's what it's telling you via the error.

[Section 6.6.1 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1) tells us:

> A member (class, interface, field, or method) of a reference (class,
>   interface, or array) type or a constructor of a class type is
>   accessible only if the type is accessible and the member or
>   constructor is declared to permit access:
>
> - If the member or constructor is declared public, then access is
>     permitted. All members of interfaces are implicitly public.
> - Otherwise, if the member or constructor is declared protected, then
>     access is permitted only when one of the following is true:
>
>   - Access to the member or constructor occurs from within the package
>       containing the class in which the protected member or constructor is
>       declared.
>   - Access is correct as described in §6.6.2.

We jump to [6.6.2.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2.2) and find:

> A protected constructor can be accessed by a class instance creation expression (that does not declare an anonymous class) only from within the package in which it is defined.

`access.test` is in a different package and you declared the constructor `protected`. Only classes within `access` can call the constructor directly (e.g. using `new` - this is what "class instance creation expression" means).

Your `data.Operations` class extends `access.test`, which is fine since `access.test` was declared `public`. Your constructor is package-private, therefore you are allowed to call:

```
Operations o = new Operations("Operations!");
```

in `data.Operations.main()`. `Operation`'s constructor calls `super(s)` which it is allowed to do because it's a subclass (in fact, it has to since there's no nullary constructor in the superclass). Note that this is *not the same thing* as calling the constructor directly via `new`.

If you were to have this:

```
Operations(String s){
    super(s);
    access.test t = new access.test(s);
}
```

It would produce the same error when trying to use `new`; you can't do that.

**A protected method has different access rules than a protected constructor.**

You've declared `test1()` in `access.test` as `protected`.

Declaring a method protected means classes in the `access` package and subclasses (regardless of package) can call it.  Therefore, the following is perfectly valid in `data.Operations.main()`:

```
Operations o = new Operations("Operations!");
o.test1("hi!");
```

If your `main()` was in a different class in your `data` package (or in another package and `Operations` had a `public` constructor), you couldn't do that.

```
package data;

public class ThirdClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // This is perfectly fine since Operations has a package-private constructor
        Operations o = new Operations("Some String");
        // This won't compile
        o.test1("hi!");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Constructors` are not **inherited**.
use it

```
 public test(String s){
          this.s = s;
          System.out.println("access.test constructor");
          }
```

Comment: @downvoter i would like to know the reason behind down vote.?

Comment: Because everything you've posted is incorrect. Well, except the inheritance part, but that has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

A subclass only access a protected members of its parent class, if it involves implementation of its parent. Therefore , you can not instantiate a parent object in a child class, if parent constructor is protected and it is in different package.

Comment: So what changes?? When should I use a protected constructor??

Comment: @user3209302 `main` can create a new `Operations` but not a new `test`.